# Angular 6 localize-router not work

Tags: angular

I use angular 6. after change the site language I am trying to translate browser url (en/home -> fr/maison),  I use @ngx-translate(https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#installation) and localize-router(https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router#localizerouterconfig).  when I am changing language the site content is being translated, but url not .    it works in angular 5, but after upgrade to angular 6 it is not working

Answer (score 0):

@angular/router@latest is not   compatible with localize router latest version,    use @angular/router <=5.2.6 version